# Range of grouped data

Tags: statistics

I am struggling with a concept .Can someone help me with it.

the concept is range is statistics which is defined as  difference between the largest and smallest values.

Now my question is, I need to find the range of a grouped data but the frequency of the last class interval that is 300-350 is 0.

In Order to calculate the range do I need to take 350 into consideration or take the last limit of the class preceding 300-350 which is 250-300?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: It is not a question but a concept. I just made an example out of it. I want to know whether we include the last limit in range if the frequency of last class interval is 0.

Comment: Have you checked out [the definition of range in statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_(statistics))?

Comment: Continuous series- Its a grouped data with class intervals like 0-10; 10-20 with respective frequencies.

Comment: Thanks for providing the link. I have checked it but still, It didn't clear my doubt.

Comment: No, there are no numbers in it. I would use the highest value in the preceding class.